# Join tables from different databases using doctrine symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I found that you can define different database connections with doctrine in [symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) so, I want to know if is possible to execute a query with a join using tables from different databases, I have been trying without success so far.

Comment: but why is it not possible? I hope you could give me a better explanation.

Comment: Seems it may be dependant on the database you're using. Folks are joining tables from different databases here - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75358/join-tables-in-two-databases-make-query-slow-is-better-to-partition-db.